# Is the Hankel matrix defined by $\ln(k)/k$ a bounded operator on $\ell^2$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I call a sequence $(b_k)$ of positive real numbers a Hilbert kernel if there is a constant $C > 0$ such that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^\infty b_{k+j}c_kc_j\,\le\,C\sum_{k=1}^\infty c_k^2
$$
holds for all sequences $(c_k)$ of positive real numbers. It is well known that $(1/k)$ is a Hilbert kernel with constant $C = \pi$. Well, now I have given
$$
b_k = 1 - \frac 1{\sqrt[k]{k}} = 1 - k^{-1/k}
$$
and I wonder whether this is a Hilbert kernel. It surely holds that $b_k > 1/k$. On the other hand, we have $k^\nu b_k\to 0$ as $k\to\infty$ for each $\nu\in (0,1)$. In particular, $b_k < 1/k^\nu$ for large $k$. So, there is some hope. I admit that I don't know that much of the whole theory - but maybe there is somebody out there who can help me out...

EDIT: In the comments, user1952009 pointed out that $b_k\sim\ln k/k$. This simplifies the expression, but does not answer my question.

EDIT2: As I learned today, an infinite matrix of the type $B = (b_{k+j})_{k,j=1}^\infty$ is called a Hankel matrix. By Nehari's theorem, the Hankel matrix $B$ defines a bounded operator on $\ell^2$ if and only if there is a sequence $(c_k)\in\ell^2$ such that the $L^2(0,2\pi)$-function
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_ke^{-ikt} + \sum_{k=0}^\infty c_ke^{ikt}
$$
lies in $L^\infty(0,2\pi)$. For the Hilbert kernel $(1/k)$ such a function is given by $ie^{-it}(\pi-t)$. However, it is still unclear whether such a function exists for $b_k = \ln (k)/k$.

Comment: your sequence $(b_k)$ defines a [symmetric kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducing_kernel_Hilbert_space) $K(i,j)= K(j,i)  = b_{i+j}$. so you want to  know if $K$ defines a bounded linear operator on $l^2$ ?

Comment: In fact, I think this is equivalent.

Comment: and $b_k = 1-k^{-1/k} = 1-\exp(\frac{-\ln k}{k}) \sim \frac{\ln k}{k}$ when $\frac{\ln k}{k} \to 0$ i.e $k\to \infty$.

Comment: Oh yes, this one looks better.